# Win32Api Python .SetCursorPos(x,y) how works?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pywin32

Hello I have this code

```
import win32api
from tkinter import *

def Cursor():
    win32api.SetCursorPos(10,10)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("")
root.configure(background="#262626")

PlayButton = Button(root, text="Cursor", command=Cursor ).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

and he give me this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
   return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\filippo\Desktop\Win32.py", line 5, in Cursor
   win32api.SetCursorPos(10,10)
TypeError: SetCursorPos() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

why? he tells me i have to put 1 argument but it should be 2 for x and y axis

Comment: your error is on line 4, `win32api.SetCurPos` takes ONE tuple and not TWO integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the coordinates as a tuple:

```
def Cursor():
    win32api.SetCursorPos((10,10))
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import win32api, win32con

pos_x = 1000
pos_y = 600
for x in range(pos_x):
    subt = int(pos_x/50)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSE_MOVED, 2, 0)
    if (x+1) == pos_x - subt:
        break

for x in range(pos_y):
    subt = int(pos_y/50)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSE_MOVED, 0, 2)
    if (x+1) == pos_y - subt:
        break
```

here in win32api the positions are different means if your screen dimensions are 1366x768 so here with win32api the dimensions are 3000x1687. I try to put cursor on given position using win32api. I use win32api because we can control cursor on games like Minecraft etc. warning :- This code is not 100% accurate here 1-2px add or subtract.